# Insert data in H2 database with Spring Boot JPA on post

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I want to save data on a registration form from my Angular app to an `H2` database using `JPA` spring boot.
But when I do the post to Spring boot to save the user data I get a `NullPointerException` on the line that calls the save method. When I just return the user data back without saving the data it works fine, but not when saving the data.

The `table` that is created:

```
Hibernate: 
    
    create table user (
       id integer not null,
        email varchar(255),
        first_name varchar(255),
        last_name varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
```

My `entity`:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    // getters, setters, and constructor, etc.
```

My `repository`:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JPAUserRepository implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, email, last_name, password)" +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")
                .setParameter(1, user.getId())
                .setParameter(2, user.getFirstName())
                .setParameter(3, user.getEmail())
                .setParameter(4, user.getLastName())
                .setParameter(5, user.getPassword())
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

The controller where I handle the post:

```
@RestController
public class Register {

private JPAUserRepository jpaUserRepository;

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/register", consumes = "application/json")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        jpaUserRepository.save(user);
        return "succesfull add";
    }
```

In the repository I have also tried `em.persist(user)` but that gave the same error.

Comment: Why are you using `@javax.persistence.Id` and `@Id` at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you error exactly comes from. But what I notices:
You are inserting your user with the id provided, however it states @Generated at the Entity - so the ID should be generated and not provided.
With Spring Boot you would usually have a Repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

You don't need any extra Methods - with calling userRepository.save(..) a User will be persisted.
I would recommend to look at https://bootify.io and create a running app, so you can check what is missing also config-wise.

Comment: Thanks! used Bootify, knowing this earlier could have saved me a lot of time hahah

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you're injecting the repo into your Register REST controller?

```
@Autowired private JPAUserRepository jpaUserRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three things I think might be the problem.

1. You are generating the the id(`@GeneratedValue`), and again setting it manually and
2. the use of  `@javax.persistence.Id` and `@Id`.
3. `EntityManger` should be injected as `@PersistenceContext`

So,

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(User user) {
    em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO user (first_name, email, last_name, password)" +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
            .setParameter(1, user.getFirstName())
            .setParameter(2, user.getEmail())
            .setParameter(3, user.getLastName())
            .setParameter(4, user.getPassword())
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

OR much convenient using jpa repos directly as stated by **Thomas**.